# On the subfield of $\mathbb C(x)$ fixed by the inversion of the variable

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, field-theory, extension-field, riemann-surfaces

Let $\mathbb C(x)$ be the field of rational functions with complex coefficients i.e. it is the fraction field of $\mathbb C[x]$ .

I am trying to explicitly determine the subfield of $\mathbb C(x)$ given by $\{f(x) \in \mathbb C(x) : f(x)=f(1/x) \}$ .

I can show that any element in the subfield of the form $p(x)/q(x)$ with $p(x), q(x)$ are polynomial of degree $1$ is actually a member of $\mathbb C$ . I'm not sure what would happen with other elements.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the element $x + 1/x$ is invariant under $x \mapsto 1/x$. Consider the field extension $K := \mathbb{C}(x + 1/x) \subset L := \mathbb{C}(x)$, it is an easy exercise to see that $K \not= L$. Consider the polynomial
$$
p(t) = t^2 -at+1 
$$
where $a = x + 1/x \in K[t]$, then, since $p(x) = 0$, this is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ and this extension has degree 2 and is Galois (every degree 2 extension is Galois), then its Galois group has order two and contains $x \mapsto 1/x$ and the identity, the only possibility is that $Gal(L/K) = \{ x \mapsto 1/x, Id\}$. Therefore $K = L^{Gal(L/K)}$, i.e. $K$ is the fixed field of $Gal(L/K)$ in L.

Edit: The [Fundamental theorem_of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) was used.

Comment: Here's an easier way to finish it off without Galois theory: Let $L$ be the field I'm trying to determine. Then $\mathbb C(x+1/x) \subseteq L \subseteq \mathbb C(x)$ . Since $L\ne \mathbb C(x)$ (because $x \notin L$) and $[\mathbb C(x): \mathbb C(x+1/x)]=2$ , so comparing extension degree, we get $\mathbb C(x+1/x)=L$